# Permanently swap Powerpoint presenter view and slide show

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint, default-settings, persistence

I have a dual monitor setup where my main monitor is monitor #2.

Whenever I start a Powerpoint slideshow, the slideshow itself appears on monitor #1, and on monitor #2 I get a "presenter view". I can use the top-bar UI to switch between the two monitors (slideshow on #2, presenter view on #1) - that works fine. However, this setting doesn't persist.

Can I make Powerpoint remember to start slideshows on monitor #2 instead of #1?

Answer (score 7):

[image: Slide Show settings]

On the Slide Show tab, under Monitors, you can choose which monitor to use as your presenter view monitor. PowerPoint will remember your choice for all presentations.

This was done on PowerPoint 2019, not sure about older versions.